# preg_match I couldn't solve

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the action path found in the form in any resource. But the path must contain "wp-comments-post.php".

I did a try below but unsuccessful.

Any Source Code

```html
<form action="https://example.com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">
```

My Try

```php
preg_match('@action="(.*?)/wp-comments-post.php"@si',$data,$matches);
```

The output I should get

```php
echo $matches[1]; // https://example.com/wp-comments-post.php
```

**A resource can have more than one form. What I need is the form action containing wp-comments-post.php.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you get, then? Your capture group above is `(.*?)`, ie. the base URL. But what are you trying to accomplish here, since you already know that the action path is `/wp-comments-post.php`, and presumably the base URL doesn't vary either? You may want to escape periods `\.` since they are regex special characters.

Comment: @MarkusAO broken html code that starts with an action.

Comment: @MarkusAO URL and source are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your pattern to include `"wp-comments-post.php"` in the match, like this:

```
preg_match('@action="(.*?/wp-comments-post.php)"@si',$data,$matches);
```

With it `$matches[1]` will contain the full url.

Comment: It is available in other forms at the source. But I want to get the one that contains "wp-comments-post.php". Your example fails, returning a long html output that starts with an url .